# Stripe API error when passing application_fee

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to collect an application fee using the Stripe API. I am sure I am missing something in the request.

Stripe complaints that it needs either of these: OAuth key, the Stripe-Account header, or the destination parameter.

I am passing in the `Stripe-Account` header.

Here is my curl request:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
    -u sk_test_<key>: \
    -H "Stripe-Account: acct_<key>" \
    -d amount=2000 -d currency=usd -d capture=true \
    -d card=tok_<key> -d description="curl" -d application_fee=48
```

Here is the response I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Can only apply an application_fee when the request is made on behalf of another account (using an OAuth key, the Stripe-Account header, or the destination parameter).",
    "param": "application_fee"
  }
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Are you passing your own account id as the platform here? If so, can you try connecting a new account to the platfor, instead?

Comment: @koopajah: I need to take a percentage of every transaction made on the ecommerce site while the rest should go to the customer's account. The `Stripe-Account` in the header has value of the customer's account.

Comment: 99% of the time, that error happens when you try to charge your own platform and pass the account id `acct_XXX` of the platform in the `Stripe-Account` header.

Comment: @koopajah It was the cause of my problem too. I created a new account (with a new email address) on Stripe, and then it was okay.

Comment: This is a common testing-environment issue that should absolutely be explained in the Stripe documentation...

Comment: Just to add: in my case, it's because I had a typo in my var name, so my `stripe_account` parameter was being sent through as blank, which is apparently the same as creating the charge on the same account as your platform. I only realised with debugging, but yeah - it's an ambiguous error.

Comment: I also encountered this issue, it was caused by me using the same account as the platform and the customer.

Answer (score 18):

To add my experience of this issue to the comments above – when you include an application fee in the request, Stripe expects that you will be charging a customer on behalf of a connected account. The application fee is the amount that should go to your platform account, as your fee for the service you provide.

Stripe throws this error if it believes that the account being paid is the platform account, and therefore it makes no sense to process a separate application fee to the same account. Ways this can happen include passing in your platform account number instead of a connected account number in the request, or a destination parameter that is set to null.

The solution is to double check the account you are making payment to is not your platform account, or not include the application fee if the charge is going to your platform. I would add a link to the relevant part of the documentation, but I'm not aware of this being covered anywhere.

Comment: my destination was null! you saved me sir.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when I accidentally had a `nil` value for the recipient's stripe account number.

The solution was to make sure `destination` was a valid stripe account code: e.g. `"acct_1HtSHv7fgYVxT5fZ"`

```
    Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_4eC39kjhkhgkhlhj1zdp7dc'

    payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      amount: @amount_minor_unit,
      currency: @currency,
      application_fee_amount: 123, 
      transfer_data: {
        destination: @stripe_account,
      },
    })

Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the
PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment (using an OAuth key or Stripe-Account header)
or destination payment (using `transfer_data[destination]`).)
```

Once I had the correct value for `@stripe_account` (instead of `nil`), the above code worked

Comment: I think it's worth noting that Stripe offers multiple ways to charge customers, either through "Direct Charges" or "Destination Charges".  Your solution is for "Destination" charges.  Depending on the platform, you may want one or the other.  One difference I found was that refunding orders as a connected account is difficult with destination charges.

Comment: @cchoe1 that's true. Funnily enough, I found myself back here because of the same error, but this time with direct charges (!). So the creation of the payment intent is different this time, but I literally made the same mistake (had a stripe connected account id of `nil`) and got the same error. Silly me. But at least we know what happens in either case now.