# Application Fee Error - Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

When I try to charge an application fee in stripe using the following code

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'amount' => $amtincents,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'source' => $stripetoken,
    'application_fee' => $appfee,
    'description' => 'Campaign Donation',
    'metadata' => array("Campaign Id" => $id)
    ), array('stripe_account' => $stripe_connected_user_id)
);
```

I get the following error

```
Array
(
    [error] => Can only apply an application_fee when the request is made on behalf of another account (using an OAuth key, the Stripe-Account header, or the destination parameter).
)
```

I have worked in stripe before and last time I did not have this problem. My donation form (for charging the donations I am using stripe) and the page I am performing the stripe operations are in the same site. I am only testing at the moment.

Comment: @Ywain
I now tried charging using the following code using the destination parameter instead of the account-header. The code for the charge looks like this    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
     'amount' => $amtincents,
     'currency' => 'usd',
     'source' => $stripetoken,
     'destination' =>   $_POST['stripe_connected_user_id'],
                'application_fee' => $appfee,
     'description' => 'Campaign Donation',
     'metadata' => array("Campaign Id" => $id)
     ));    I now get 

Array ( 
[error] => The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account. 
)

Comment: @Ywain I now tried charging using the following code for charging and used the destination parameter instead of the account-header. 

The code for the charge looks like this 

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array( 'amount' => $amtincents, 'currency' => 'usd', 'source' => $stripetoken, 'destination' => $_POST['stripe_connected_user_id'], 'application_fee' => $appfee, 'description' => 'Campaign Donation', 'metadata' => array("Campaign Id" => $id) )); 

I now get the error 

( [error] => The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using an older version of [Stripe's PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#stripe-php-bindings) that does not support the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header. Ideally, you should be using the latest version (4.4.0 at this time).

If that's not the issue, then it's likely that the `$stripe_connected_user_id` variable has an empty value. Make sure that the variable contains valid account ID (`"acct_..."`).

Comment: I now tried charging using the following code using the destination parameter instead of the account-header. The code for the charge looks like this
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
     'amount' => $amtincents,
     'currency' => 'usd',
     'source' => $stripetoken,
     'destination' =>   $_POST['stripe_connected_user_id'],
                'application_fee' => $appfee,
     'description' => 'Campaign Donation',
     'metadata' => array("Campaign Id" => $id)
     ));

I now get.
Array
(
   [error] => The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account.
)

Comment: I now tried charging using the following code for charging and used the destination parameter instead of the account-header. 

The code for the charge looks like this 

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array( 'amount' => $amtincents, 'currency' => 'usd', 'source' => $stripetoken, 'destination' => $_POST['stripe_connected_user_id'], 'application_fee' => $appfee, 'description' => 'Campaign Donation', 'metadata' => array("Campaign Id" => $id) )); 

I now get the error ( [error] => The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account. )

Comment: @jai This error message means that the account ID that you're providing is the platform's account's ID (i.e. your own account's ID). You need to provide the ID of an account that is connected to the platform, not that of the platform itself.

Comment: This account id was created when I tried to follow the steps given in the following page

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts

I had stored the stripe_user_id the process in the above page  returned and I stored that in my db. I am trying to use that for collect application fees. Sorry for the trouble but can you explain in a little more detail or point me to a link which clearly tells me what is the difference?

Comment: Please note my comment above. Your explanation awaited. Is it just a testing environment problem as given here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909342/stripe-api-error-when-passing-application-fee

Comment: Ywain I had worked with stripe some 8 months back. I completely forgot that when it comes to standalone accounts there is a platform account and a standalone account involved. I created a separate test account with a new email id and treated that as my standalone account and the other account is my platform account. Things are working fine now. Thank you so much for the help.