# Stripe integration in Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe in my Laravel Application. I am trying to use [this](https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart) (Pay with Card) Service of Stripe.

I am using below code after redirection from Stripe

```
try {
            $charge = Charge::create([
                'amount'          => $price * 100,
                'currency'        => 'gbp',
                'source'          => $request->stripeToken,
                'application_fee' => 123,          // Here is the issue , if I remove this line it works fine.
            ], [
                'stripe_account' => $stripe_id,
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return back()->withError('Something went wrong while processing your payment.');
        }
```

I am getting below error

[image]

**UPDATE**

Now I am using below code.

```
 try {
        $charge = Charge::create([
            'amount'      => $price * 100,
            'currency'    => 'gbp',
            'source'      => $request->stripeToken,
            "destination" => array(
                "amount"  => 877,
                "account" => "ca_CxKfJvDzUYe3NUpOYZcRofjlZzE8OYCq",
            ),
        ], [
            'stripe_account' => $stripe_id,
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return back()->withError('Something went wrong while processing your payment.');
    }
```

I am getting below error

[image]

Comment: This is the same issue and has comments explaining the reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909342/stripe-api-error-when-passing-application-fee

Comment: Thanks @TheFallen. Should I use 2 account for `application_fee` ?

Comment: @abu-abu Yes, `application_fee` only makes sense if you are using [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) and have another Stripe account that is connected to yours. If you're just doing a regular charge of a customer you don't need it, or `stripe_account`. But if you are using Connect, then `stripe_account` should be the ID of the connected account, not yours as the platform.

Comment: Thanks @karllekko. I am using this (https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart) Pay with Card .

Comment: But your code doesn't match that, it looks more like you are using [this](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#collecting-platform-fees). But anyway, that `ca_xxx` ID is not the ID of a connected account, it's an ID for your platform to use when [connecting a Standard account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts). I'd suggest you follow the steps in that doc and actually connect an account to yours first, before trying to charge them :)

Comment: Thanks @karllekko. Actually I am using Laravel php framework. After payment I am redirecting users to those codes.

Comment: It might help to explain(edit the question) exactly what you're trying to do here. From what I can see, you are trying to charge a customer on behalf of a connected account and then take a fee. But you don't seem to have a connected account(check your [dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/applications/users/overview)) since you don't have an `acct_xxx` ID for them. I would suggest reading through the Connect docs again, and maybe explaining in your question what your goal is.

Comment: Thanks @karllekko. How to get a connected account ?

Comment: I'd suggest you start here : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/quickstart and work through the docs.

Comment: Thanks @karllekko. May be I have connected account. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcoKa.png

Comment: If you do, they will be under Connect->Accounts on the left, not on that Settings page.

Comment: Thanks @karllekko. May be I have to activate my account for that.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0MJV.png

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.
this working fine for me .
first create customer and get customer id and make charge 
this is the step .
any other issue ..then ping here

```
                    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                        "email" => $cus_email,
                        "source" => $token,
                    ));
                    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                        "amount" => $TotalAmountPayment,
                        "currency" => "usd",
                        "customer" => $customer->id
                    ));
                     $customer_payamt=($charge->amount)/100;;
                     $customer_id=$charge->customer;
                     $balance_transaction_id=$charge->balance_transaction;
                     $payment_status_resp=$charge->outcome['seller_message'];
                     $cardlast4=$charge->source['last4'];
```